Wrapping text in fancy section headers
I am trying to make fancy section headers based on this question.
The result is very nice but long titles run out of the page as can be seen in the image below.

I tried to include some \raisebox to wrap the text based on the answer to this question but it did not wrap the text.
To be honest, I am not even certain the text should be wrapped alone. The blue line should probably be wrapped as well but what of the colored section number?
Does someone has an elegant solution to the problem?
MWE
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% Formatting the sections
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\tikz[baseline=(a.base), overlay]{
        \node[fill=blue, anchor=south west, outer sep=0, draw=none, inner sep=.5mm, 
        text=white,font=\large, text width=1.5cm, align=center, minimum height=8.5mm,
        label={right:#1}
        ] (a) {\thesection};
        \draw[blue, ultra thick] ($(a.south east)!.15!(a.north east)$) --++ (\textwidth-1.6cm,0);
    }
}
{1em}
{}
\begin{document}
    \section{Some test section with a very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\end{document}


I'd use the last argument for the title, not a “label” to the TikZ picture.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Formatting the sections
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\AlMaDecoration}
  {1.8cm}
  {\AlMaTitle}
\newcommand{\AlMaDecoration}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base), overlay]
    \node[
      fill=blue,
      anchor=south west,
      outer sep=0,
      draw=none,
      inner sep=.5mm, 
      text=white,
      font=\large,
      text width=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      minimum height=8.5mm,
    ] (a) {\thesection};
    \draw[blue, ultra thick] ($(a.south east)!.15!(a.north east)$) --++ (\textwidth-1.6cm,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\AlMaTitle}[1]{\parbox[b]{\dimeval{\textwidth-1.8cm}}{\strut#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Some test section not very long}

\section{Some test section with a very very very very very 
  very very very very very very long title}

\end{document}



Thanks, would it be possible to have the extended text wrapping below the blue line with a continued blue line below? I don't know if it is possible

@AlMa Just for testing, replace \parbox[b] with \parbox[t]. Now look at the output: it's horrible and another blue line would make it even worse.
